# Aluminum vs. Wooden Drumsticks?

Tags: drums, drum-kits, drum-stick

I am wondering about the differences between these materials when playing drums. I've always used wooden sticks - and all the drummers I have played with, as well.

But, I see the potential in using aluminum (or aluminium ;) drumsticks - not just for the superior durability but, also in the more springy rebound... Also, to anyone with experience in using the two types, is there a difference in sound?

What are the pros and cons of using either?

Answer (score 3):

Confessing to never having used them! However - several 'advantages'.

Replaceable parts - the sleeves and tips are replaceable, meaning they will effectively pay for themselves better over time than having to replace complete wooden sticks. And they won't break as easily!

They flex more than wooden sticks, and return quicker, too, meaning they're effectively quicker in use. That may well depend on which wooden sticks are being compared.

USP would appear to be in para.2. Less wastage, and longer life. We all know how older wooden sticks end up - and they're not that good as firewood. Save the world..!

The 'recoil' from them is a lot less than that from wooden sticks, so it is less tiring to play with them, and theoretically at least, arthritis and carpel tunnel are less likely to be caused by drummers using them.